# How to change view after getting successful request android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, request, android-view

I have this piece of code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);


        if (roomArray == null || roomArray.isEmpty()) {
            roomArray = getTablesList(new VolleyCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ArrayList<RoomsClass> result) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            ArrayList<View> tableList = new ArrayList<>();

            ArrayList<Tables> tables;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IsNotNull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            tables = roomArray.get(0).getTables();
            GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                tableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) tableView.findViewById(R.id.table_number);
                textView.setText(tables.get(i).getTableNumber());
                GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(i / 5);
                GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(i);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
                gridLayout.addView(tableList.get(i), i, params);
            }
        }
        return layout;
    }
```

so I have onSuccess, but I cant add views to my fragment. I need to somehow call all methods after onSuccess, but its inner class so I can't handle anything there. So what is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you inflating two fragments in createView?

```
tableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
```

Comment: yes i do, is it wrong?) i just use 1 inflator for 2 view. maybe i should use layoutinflater or something, but thats not the point yet.

Answer (score 0):

have u try to use handler to solve this problem , the use of handler can avoid do something in a inner class.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {  
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {   
               switch (msg.what) {   
                    case a:   
                        //do somthing 
                        break;   
               }   
               super.handleMessage(msg);   
          }   
     };
```

Comment: what tipe of handler, some adapter or what? i dont, tell me more if it help with this.